# Trying to create XPath from this HTML snippet

Tags: xpath, selenium

I have played for a while writing XPath but am unable to come up with exactly what I want.

I'm trying to write XPath for link(click1 and click2 in code snippet below) based on known text(myidentity in code snippet below). Can someone take a look into and suggest possible solution?

HTML code snippet:

```
<div class="abc">
  <a onclick="mycontroller.goto('xx','yy'); return false;" href="#">
    <img src="images/controls/inheritance.gif"/>
  </a>
  myidentity
  <span>
    <a onclick="mycontroller.goto('xx','yy'); return false;" href="#">click1</a>
    <a onclick="mycontroller.goto('xx','yy'); return false;" href="#">click2</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Html code snippet:
==================


<div class="abc">
<a onclick="mycontroller.goto('xx,'yy'); return false;"
href="#">
<img src="images/controls/inheritance.gif"/>
</a>
myidentity
<span>
<a onclick="mycontroller.goto('xx,'yy'); return false;" 
href="#">
click1</a>
 
<a onclick=""mycontroller.goto('xx,'yy');
 return false;" 
href="#">
click2 </a>
</span>
</div>

Comment: please note that there are similar click1 and click2 on same page but with different myidentity text. Thats why we need to write such xpath based on myidentity

Comment: Please put all your code in the body of your question and use the code format on it (icon looks like binary).

Comment: prodigitalson, I added html code in body of question but I didn't see it appeared after I post the comment and thats why I pasted html code in comment field. Sorry

Comment: Actually it was in the body of the question... it was jsutn rendering the html instead of being in a pre/code tag. I fixed it for you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Macro's answer -  this form should be used.

```
//div[text()[contains(., "myidentity")]]/span/a[2]
```

The following only works with one section of text in the containing div.

You'll need to select based on the text containing your identity text.

Xpath for click1

```
//div[contains(text(),"myidentity")]/span/a[1]
```

Xpath for click2

```
//div[contains(text(),"myidentity")]/span/a[2]
```

Comment: In the example provided there is more than one text element to the div tag which would cause the above to fail as the first argument to contains must be a single element

Comment: @Macros: That's correct. `//div[text()[contains(., "myidentity")]]/span/a[2]` is better.

Comment: +1 - have updated my answer to reflect the different predicate

Comment: great ...thank you guys this is xpaths you provided works fine

Comment: I just slightly modified xpath to click on specific link by addng anchor text 
//div[text()[contains(., "myidentity")]]/span/a[./text()='click[1/2]'

Comment: You should accept Macros' answer, since he has what you actually used.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say without seeing the rest of the HTML but the following should work:

```
//div[text()[contains(., "myidentity")]]/span/a
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use XPath here, you could use a CSS locator. These are often faster and more compatible across different browsers.

```
css=div:contains(myidentity) > span a:nth-child(1) //click1
css=div:contains(myidentity) > span a:nth-child(2) //click2
```

Note that the `>` is only required to workaround a bug in the CSS locator library used by Selenium.