# How can i write my own xpath from the html code

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have followig HTML code and want X path for the text "Analytics & Research"

```
<div id="LLCompositePageContainer" class="column-wrapper">
    <div id="compositePageTitleDiv">
        <h1 class="page-header">Analytics &amp; Research</h1>   
 </div>
```

I am getting following `xpath` using chrome, but that didnt work.

```
//*[@id="compositePageTitleDiv"]
```

this is my code

```
WebElement header = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='LLCompositePageContainer']/div[@id='compositePageTitleDiv']/h1[@class='page-header']"));        

String header2 = header.getText();

System.out.println(header2);
```

and following error I am getting

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   Unable to find element with xpath ==
>   //div[@id='LLCompositePageContainer']/div[@id='compositePageTitleDiv']/h1[@class='page-header']
>   (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 10.34 seconds For documentation on this
>   error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212548/how-to-get-the-absolute-xpath-for-an-element-within-firebug

Comment: unfortunately i can not user Firefox or firebug due to the IT policy, thanks

Comment: Please define "didn't work", provide your relevant code, and the error message / behavior you're getting.

Comment: Yeah, what do you mean "didn't work"?  perhaps this element is nested inside an iframe, so your code needs to switch to it.

Comment: i think you are correct, element is part of iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use the below xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='compositePageTitleDiv']/h1")).getText();
```

If the element is inside the iframe. Then use the below code:

```
// Switching to the frame
driver.switchTo().frame(<name>);

// Storing the value of the Analytics & Research
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='compositePageTitleDiv']/h1")).getText();

// Switching back to original window
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it can be used :

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='compositePageTitleDiv']"));
```

Or in case it is nested, can be accessed like this as well

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[3]/div[3]/"));
```

this is just a rough syntax.

Comment: Thanks, i know the syntax, but the x path that either i am getting  from chrome or the one which i tried to create based on my research didnt worked.

Comment: this is similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596264/trying-to-create-xpath-from-this-html-snippet?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `Xpath` here if you could simply locate the element using `By.id()`. Asuming are using `Java`, you should try as below :-

```
WebElement el = drive.findElement(By.id("compositePageTitleDiv"));
String text = el.getText();
```

**Edited** :- If element not found, may it is timing issues you need to implement `WebDriverWait` to wait for element until visible on the page as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, implicitWait);
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("compositePageTitleDiv")));
String text = el.getText();
```

**Note** :- if your element is inside any frame, you need to switch that frame before finding element as :- `driver.switchTo().frame("your frame name or id");`

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: unable to find element by id, getting below error Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == compositePageTitleDiv (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.40 seconds

Comment: @Amol1981 you need to implement `WebDriverWait` then, see updated answer..

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
//div[@id='LLCompositePageContainer']/div[@id='compositePageTitleDiv']/
h1[contains(text(),'Analytics')]
```

This is the best way to reach to the specific web element, using contains minimize the chances of error.

Answer (score -1):

The correct xpath is

```
//div[@id='LLCompositePageContainer']
  /div[@id='compositePageTitleDiv']
  /h1[@class='page-header']
```

But you could have find your answer easily with some researchs on google...

Comment: Thanks, i see how you have created the x path, i used the same but that didnt worked, do you know any tutorial using which i can learn to write x path?